# How to replace a text attachment with a custom drawing with NSLayoutManager?

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring, nstextattachment, nslayoutmanager, nstextstorage

My ultimate goal is to give the user the ability to **split a text inside an `NSTextView` or `UITextView` into several sections**, where two subsequent sections are visually separated by a custom view separator (possibly, but not necessarily a horizontal rule – I want to be able to adjust the visual appearance of the separator without a hassle).

[image: Example screenshot for section break separators]

I need a solution that works on **both platforms: macOS and iOS**.

(My [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55155134/2062785) focused on a solution for macOS and there is one that makes use of `NSTextAttachmentCell`s which are not available on iOS.)

My current approach to tackling this problem is the following:

1. I have a button in the window's toolbar to insert a section break.
2. When the user taps that button, I create a new attributed string with no text but with a text attachment:

   ```
   let attachment = SectionChangeTextAttachment()
   let attachmentString = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment)
   ```

   *(`SectionChangeTextAttachment` is a custom subclass of `NSTextAttachment` that I created in order to be able to distinguish this section break attachment from other possible attachments.)*
3. I insert that `attachmentString` to text storage at the current cursor position:

   ```
   textStorage.insert(attachmentString, at: textView.selectedRange().location)
   ```
4. I create a custom `NSLayoutManager` subclass. Its task is to find all the attachments of class `SectionChangeTextAttachment` and replace all occurrences with a separator drawing (or glyph?). And here's the problem: With Apple's limited and partially outdated documentation, I cannot figure out how to do this.

So my question is:

**How can I make my layout manager replace attachment characters (with a specific attachment) with a custom drawing (of a separator) that takes up more space than the character / glyph?**

(I guess there is no glyph for the attachment character and thus the layout manager doesn't provide any space for it.)

**Which methods do I need to override in order to make this work?**

(Does this approach even make sense to begin with?)

Comment: I would have gone with a `UITableView`, with cells as `UITextView` and headers views (or footer) as custom separator.

Comment: I thought of that, but the problem is that you cannot select the entire text then — or more specifically you cannot make selections that spread across different sections (which is a requirement for me). And copy & paste gets really difficult as well...